# Text editor show inserts and deletions

Tags: .net, wpf, text

Much like the edit history on SO I would like to show inserts and deletions.  I don't need the bullet, link, or other formatting.  Just original text in white, deleted in red, and added in green.  What tool(s) might I use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google diff-match-patch does what you want and is available in c#. https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Once you have the list of Diffs, you'll need to find a way to display them in a `RichTextBox` by using some kind of converter that takes in a collection of Diffs and returns a `FlowDocument`. Your `FlowDocument` will be constructed from a list of `Run` objects which can be given a color. You can then assign the `FlowDocument` to the `RichTextBox.Document` property.

The first thing I made was a view model wrapper around the `Diff` object

```
public class DiffViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Diff _model;

    public DiffViewModel(Diff model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public Operation Operation { get { return _model.operation; } }
    public string Text { get { return _model.text; } }
}
```

And a conversion method to turn a collection of these into a FlowDocument

```
private FlowDocument DiffsToFlowDocument(IEnumerable<DiffViewModel> differences)
{
    var doc = new FlowDocument();
    var p = new Paragraph();

    foreach (var diff in differences)
    {
        var run = new Run(diff.Text);

        switch (diff.Operation)
        {
            case Operation.DELETE:
                run.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral);
                run.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
                run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF252526"));
                break;
            case Operation.INSERT:
                run.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
                run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF252526"));
                break;
            case Operation.EQUAL:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        p.Inlines.Add(run);
    }

    doc.Blocks.Add(p);
    return doc;
}
```

You can then create a `RichTextBox`, bind the `DataContext` to your list of `DiffViewModels` and ensure that the `Document` is created and assigned when the `DataContext` changes. Unfortunately, the `RichTextBox.Document` is not bindable so we have to use some code behind to achieve this.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="CurrentBody" DataContextChanged="Differences_OnDataContextChanged" DataContext="{Binding CurrentDifferences}" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" />
```

Comment: OK that identifies matches and differences but I don't translate that to "original text in white, deleted in red, and added in green" like on SO.

Comment: Updated my answer with your next steps

Comment: Thanks not the path I imagined but may be the way to get there.  My concern is a delete of the same word in paragraph one but not paragraph three.  But I just need to give it a try.  My though is since the editor is hosted I would track the position directly.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck and I'll provide some code. I had to do this exact thing in WPF last year.

Comment: Cool I did not know the diffs looked like that.  Let me try this out before I give it the check.